Connecting SQL Developer to MySQL database
I have Oracle's SQL Developer 24.3 (uses Java 17 in the background) and want to connect to MySQL Server 8.0.18. Using MySQL's J-connector I can connect to MySQL database (Tools->Preferences->Database->Third Party JDBC Drivers)
I can connect, browse database tables/views, even execute SQL queries but when I want to show table content in table in GUI (Data tab) I get error message "can't parse argument number: :SCHEMA". It seems that SQL Developer sends this parameter to JDBC and it cannot process it correctly
(Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ":SCHEMA")
How to solve this issue?

There are differences between Oracle and MySQL dialects, and Oracle SQL Developer almost certainly uses the Oracle dialect, so it won't be compatible with MySQL.

Contrary to your comment @Barmar, SQL developer works with MySQL but there's a little problem with sending of one parameter :SCHEME in background which JDBC driver cannot accept/translate.
